# Come posso capire "portare"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs, meaning

Buonasera. Vorrei capire cosa significa "portare" in italiano. So che significa "portare qualcosa a qualcuno", ma ho un problema. In spagnolo abbiamo due verbi: *llevar* (significa "portare qualcosa a qualche persona oppure luogo") e *traer* (significa "portare da qualche luogo qualcosa al luogo dove tu stai"), ma parlando in italiano, "portare" significa entrambi i verbi e non so come vedere la differenza. In spagnolo questi verbi sono antonimi.

Ho avuto questo dubbio perché ho fatto un esercizio su Duolingo che mi chiedeva di tradurre

> Porta il giornale a tuo nonno.

Ho messo "trae el periódico a tu abuelo" e dice che ho torto, perché il verbo esatto è "lleva".

Comment: Non so se ho capito bene la domanda. In italiano questa differenza viene espressa dal complemento. Se dico "portami" intendo che tu lo porti qua dove sono io. Se dico "ti porto" intendo movimento fino alla tua posizione.

Comment: Se ho capito bene il dubbio, suppongo che la soluzione sia nell'aggiungere a “portare” degli avverbi o altre specificazioni (portare con sé, portare via) o nell'usare altri verbi più specifici (dare, offrire, togliere...). Ma penso che l'unica persona che può risolvere compiutamente questo dubbio sia @Charo.

Comment: Non capisco bene qual è il tuo problema. In effetti, entrambi i verbi spagnoli "traer"  e "llevar" si possono tradurre come "portare". Ma il problema è che non capisci frasi come "mi ha portato un regalo", che si può tradurre come "me ha traído un regalo", o "porta questo a tuo padre", che si  può tradurre come "lleva esto a tu padre"?

Comment: @DaG: Non sono sicura di essere la persona capace di chiarire il dubbio. Forse il problema è che in catalano esiste anche il verbo "portar" che può essere tradotto in castigliano come "traer" o "llevar". Quindi, non ho mai avuto problemi per capire il significato di "portare" e non riesco a capire quale sia il dubbio.

Comment: @Charo: Ah, non sapevo di *portar* in catalano!

Comment: @Hamr: Potresti aggiungere alla tua domanda alcuni esempi di frasi in cui hai difficoltà a capire il significato di "portare"?

Comment: Grazie mille a tutti! Ho gia capito che si puó usare entrambi significati. Il mio dubbio era perchè ho fatto un esercizio su Duolingo, tradurre: "Porta il giornale a tuo nonno" e ho messo "trae el periódico a tu abuelo" e dice che ho torto, perchè il verbo esatto era "lleva", perciò il mio dubbio. Adesso soltanto devo capire secondo il complemento della frase. (veramente mi dispiace, vorrei qualcosa più diretto. Vabbeh, non importa!) Grazie a tutti!

Comment: @Hamr:  Secondo me, per imparare una nuova lingua devi cercare di capire le frasi, ma non necessariamente essere capace di tradurle in una altra lingua. Perlomeno io ho sempre fatto così e posso assicurarti di essere una pessima traduttrice!

Comment: La frase sul nonno significa “prendi il giornale; va' dove sta tuo nonno; da' il giornale al nonno”. Questo ti è chiaro? Come poi si renda in castigliano o in altre lingue è un po' off-topic per questo sito. (E non fidarti al 100% di quello che dice Duolinguo.)

Comment: @Hamr:  Mi sono permessa di aggiungere alla tua domanda quello che ci hai spiegato sull'esercizio di Duolingo (che è il fatto concreto che ha motivato il tuo dubbio) perché penso che così sia più facile di scrivere una risposta.

Comment: @DaG: In riferimento al tuo commento, penso che il dubbio di Hamr è se la frase significhi "**vieni** dove sta tuo nonno" oppure "**va'** dove sta tuo nonno".

Comment: Grazie, @Charo. Se capisco bene, è un tipo di distinzione deittica simile a quella che in italiano è presente appunto in andare/venire, questo/quello/(codesto), qui/lì/(costì) e altrove, ma non c'è per “portare”.

Comment: Sì, @DaG, è così.

Answer (score 5):

In effetti, il verbo italiano "portare" si può tradurre in spagnolo sia come "llevar", sia come "traer". La frase che ha motivato il tuo dubbio,

> Porta il giornale a tuo nonno

si può tradurre in spagnolo come

> Trae el periódico a tu abuelo

se, per esempio, io che sto parlando sono accanto al nonno e il giornale è lontano. Facendo una spiegazione simile a quella di @DaG nel suo commento, questo significa “prendi il giornale; **vieni** dove sta tuo nonno; da' il giornale al nonno”. Ma può essere anche

> Lleva el periódico a tu abuelo

se il giornale è accanto a me e il nonno è lontano. Questo invece significa quello che ha detto @DaG nel suo commento, cioè, “prendi il giornale; **va'** dove sta tuo nonno; da' il giornale al nonno”.

Spesso sarà il contesto a dirti se "portare" corrisponda a "traer" oppure "llevar", ma a volte può darsi che non sia sufficiente per poter decidere quale sia la traduzione più adatta. Se hai soltanto la frase "Porta il giornale a tuo nonno" e non hai nessuna informazione sulla posizione del giornale o del nonno, non puoi decidere quale delle due possibili traduzioni è la migliore. Secondo me, per imparare una lingua devi cercare di capire qual è la informazione che ti dà una frase o un testo, senza necessariamente essere capace di fare una traduzione. Succede che i verbi spagnoli "traer" e "llevar" ci danno informazione sul fatto se il soggetto si allontana o invece si avvicina, mentre il verbo italiano "portare" non ci dà questa informazione.